# Below code upload files to ftp and return file and byte count, how to make it run parallel?

Tags: c#

```
  private async Task Upload(Ftp ftpHost)
     {
         //var assetImages is List<FileInfo>  
         var uploadedOrderFileByteCount = 0;
         var uploadedOrderFileCount = 0;

         foreach (var fi in assetImages.Where(fi => fi.Exists))
         {
             uploadedOrderFileCount++;

             var count = ftp.Upload(fi);

             uploadedOrderFileByteCount += await count;
             fi.Delete();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Take a look at this simple `Parallel.ForEach()` example: [How to: Write a simple Parallel.ForEach loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple `async` parallelism by using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
private async Task Upload(Ftp ftpHost)
{
   //var assetImages is List<FileInfo>  

   var uploadTasks = assetImages.Where(fi => fi.Exists).Select(async fi =>
   {
      var ret = await ftp.Upload(fi);
      fi.Delete();
      return ret;
   }).ToArray();
   var counts = await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks);
   var uploadedOrderFileByteCount = counts.Sum();
   var uploadedOrderFileCount = counts.Count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I put your code into try catch and tested, and found if any upload task failed, for example, cancelled, the counts will be 0. how to ignore any single failed upload until all upload finished, then count only complete tasks?

Comment: With the code I provided above, if any task failed, then the counts aren't even defined (so they won't be 0 or any other value). If you want to observe all the tasks, then walk through `uploadTasks` after `await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks)` raises an exception.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I will add code to only count complete tasks and ignore failed.